# How to set disable for tokenize2

Tags: node.js, pug, tokenize2

Can anyone help me how to set *disable* for the *select* generated by tokenize2 plugin.
In profile_setting.js:

```
let industries = ["Internet", "Health Care"];
var industries_html = '';
for(var i = 0; i< industries.length; i++){
      industries_html += '<option value="'+industries[i]+'" selected>'+industries[i]+'</option>';            
}
$('#tags-industry-profile-setting').html(industries_html);
$('#tags-industry-profile-setting').tokenize2({
        searchFromStart: false,
        tokensAllowCustom: false,
        searchHighlight: false,
        tokensMaxItems: 1,
        placeholder: "    Industries"
    });
```

In industry.pug:

```
select(id="tags-industry-profile-setting" name="industry" multiple="")
```

Thanks